# Mouse and Keyboard stop working, Num lock flashesh on keyboard input

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse

Usually after a weekend when I return to office, my keyboard and mouse won't work at all. If I hit keys on the keyboard, the Numlock light will flash once for each keypress. Re-plugging the devices (both USB) doesn't help.

I've disabled power saving for the devices and the USB hubs, and disabled sleep on the PC. This happens just after one night sometimes as well, maybe twice a month. The after-weekend freeze is almost every time. It's happened three times during use of the PC as well, but that's really rare. Problem has been ongoing for half-a-year.

There is no event in system log when this happends, so I have no idea what might be causing the issue.

System: Win 7 Home Premium 64bit, i7-2600, 16GB Ram, 3 Monitors (nVidia GeForce 510 and GT 610), Razer mouse, Qpad mechanical keyboard.
Usage: Running Oracle VM Virtualbox (Centos) and 1-3 browsers, Tortoise SVN, WinSCP, Sublime Text, Mozilla Thunderbird, few PuTTy sessionsand f.lux.

I used to have a "regular" OEM keyb\mouse and they did the exact same, so it's probably not a mouse driver issue. When the controls freeze, I can still shut down the PC by hitting the power button and the OS will safely power down, so it's not an OS freeze - every program still works.

Comment: I think it might be RAM related as I'm quite sure I had no problems before upgrading to 16GB, not 100% sure since I got the memory after 2 weeks of having this system, and I just might have been lucky before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the OS solved the issue. Still no idea what was the underlying issue.